# specify topic name for sleuth-kaka using spring-cloud-stream

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am trying to set kafka as destination for sleuth reporting. Everything is workign fine except sleuth keeps sending to default topic sleuth. I wanted spans to be send to customized topic such as **test** as below

Below as my configuration for kafka channel.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9094
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=localhost:2182
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=test
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

appreciate for any advice?

Answer (score 3):

The Stream SLeuth's channel is called Sleuth. Just change `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.sleuth.destination=yourCustomName`. That way you will start sending / reading the Sleuth's spans from a different topic.